# How can I change the default launch.json file automatically created by the VS Code debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I automatically create a launch.json file in the VSCode debugger (`Run and Debug` --> `create a launch.json file`) the following file is created:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I change the default settings so that also the "args" key is created with some default parameters?
Or how do I set "justMyCode": false by default?

NOTE that I don't want to change the global setting.json file since [it will be ignored if a launch.json file is created](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18401#issuecomment-291901322).

Thanks!

I've tried looking with `grep -l -r "justMyCode" ~/.vscode-server` where this variable was set but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267381/11107541. From my testing, user settings.json's `launch` property is _combined_ with workspace launch.json instead of ignored. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't since:
1) `launch.json` overwrites some parameters such as "justMyCode"
2) It is more useful for me if a different `launch.json` file is created, that is quite different from the default one. So that I can make minor changes for all future projects

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21486